# ERC-20 tokens parked (now trapped) in smart contract pre-mist and after Ethereum Wallet sunsetting

Tags: erc-20, mist

I have the keystore file, paper wallet and passphrase for the wallet.

On my very first day learning about ethereum I installed Ethereum Wallet that does not get supported anymore. I downloaded the blockchain without corruption in time sync because it was small enough to not require months to get the entire blockchain.

I was told to use my wallet to create a contract because ERC-20 tokens were to be sent to me and they needed to be sent to a contract, not the wallet. I got the tokens. I also created an new 2nd contract and I easily used the graphic user interface to pass those tokens back and forth between the contracts. I stopped doing that because I learned I was paying gas. I was satisfied that everything was in order.

Now today I want to move those ERC tokens out of the contract. I can't use Ethereum Wallet because that project is dead now. I can't use geth to download the blockchain because after months of downloading it will grow to be corrupted at the end and never finish syncing due to errors.

Can ethereum wallets hold ERC-20 tokens? Or is it true that only contracts can hold them?

What is an ABI/JSON interface that I can use to move the tokens out? Whatever I try never looks like the GUI I was using on the Ethereum Wallet application. I see commands I can select but there is no explanation for the fields I need to enter. I see commands I can select but there is no explanation if I am only moving ETH and not the tokens.

I've spent years trying to untie this knot. I will read responses to this thread and try everything I am told. Then I will respond with an explanation how that idea never worked, either.

Thank you because it is really crazy trying to do my own research on this one. It has been a massive waste of effort over here on my end. I don't want to create a new token. I want to use the tokens I have that were created only 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: Probably what you deployed was a multisig contract. If you have the owner account, the contract address it should be possible to extract the ERC20 tokens. Since the contracts code was open source the ABI should be on github, the ABI contains the name of the functions implemented by the contract and the parameters required to call them. Unfortunately I don't know a wallet that has an easy interface for interaction with contracts. Both MyCrypto and MyEtherWallet has the option but they are very rough.

Comment: Here is a guide from MyCrypto how to interact with a mist multisig wallet https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/how-to-interact-with-a-multisig-contract (good for ether but not for ERC20 tokens). They have an additional guide for that task https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/how-to-send-tokens-from-a-multisig-contract. I think MyCrypto guys are pretty cool they have telegram and discord channels where they hangout. If you have some trouble try to contact them.

Comment: Thank you Ismael. I feel this brings me very close to where I need to go! I will try and see if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you, Ismael. I've finally got it figured out with your advice. It was amazing how many years and hours this has been driving me nuts. But after many failed attempts I had one of those attempts work. I almost didn't even notice that it had worked. This advice got me onto the bottom of the learning curve.

Comment: The trick that got my mind set straight was looking very closely at the old successful transactions I performed years ago instead of looking at my failed attempts that are more recent. It was like learning to read for the first time. And then the guides you gave me made more sense to me.